# Changing the time stamp on my Wordpress website

Tags: php, wordpress, date, timestamp

In the google SERP my time stamps are the creation date of my articles, but as I regularly update them, I would like to show the updated date instead. I read that Google uses the first date that it finds and that is my creation date(updated date is written after that).

**What I want to change in the code**

Instead of this order:

Created on: 2 July 2010, Updated on: 5 july 2016

I want to create the following:

Updated on: 5 July 2016, Created on: 2 July 2010

Basically just switch the two dates so that google will pick the correct date.

On my page.php the following was written

```
                <div class="blog_info contentsbox <?php st_hidden_class(); ?>">
                <p>Created on：
                    <time class="entry-date" datetime="<?php the_time(DATE_W3C); ?>">
                        <?php the_time( 'Y/m/d' ); ?>
                    </time>
                    <br>
                    <?php if ( $mtime = st_get_mtime( 'Y/m/d' ) ) {
                        echo 'Updated on：', $mtime;
                    } ?>
                </p>
            </div>
```

And on my singe PHP:

```
                    <div class="blogbox <?php st_hidden_class(); ?>">
                    <p><span class="kdate"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>&nbsp;
            <time class="entry-date date updated" datetime="<?php the_time(DATE_W3C); ?>">
                <?php the_time( 'Y/m/d' ); ?>
            </time>
            &nbsp;
                            <?php if ( $mtime = st_get_mtime( 'Y/m/d' ) ) {
                                echo ' <i class="fa fa-repeat"></i>&nbsp; ', $mtime;
                            } ?>
            </span></p>
                </div>
```

Thank you in advance for the help

Comment: did my answer help you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="blog_info contentsbox <?php st_hidden_class(); ?>">
    <p>
        <?php if ( $mtime = st_get_mtime( 'Y/m/d' ) ) {
            echo 'Updated on：', $mtime;
        } ?>
        <br>
        Created on：
        <time class="entry-date" datetime="<?php the_time(DATE_W3C); ?>">
            <?php the_time( 'Y/m/d' ); ?>
        </time>                        
    </p>
</div>
```

and the other one:

```
<div class="blogbox <?php st_hidden_class(); ?>">
    <p>
        <span class="kdate"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>&nbsp;
            <?php if ( $mtime = st_get_mtime( 'Y/m/d' ) ) {
                echo ' <i class="fa fa-repeat"></i>&nbsp; ', $mtime;
            } ?>
            &nbsp;
            <time class="entry-date date updated" datetime="<?php the_time(DATE_W3C); ?>">
                <?php the_time( 'Y/m/d' ); ?>
            </time>
        </span>
    </p>
</div>
```